# Having trouble with .remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so this line of code works; the `i` is just a var going up:

```
i=3;                     
i++;

$('#pallet_info').append('<li id="Pallet'+i+'" class="inactive"> <span class="itemNumber">'+i+'</span>'+ime+'</li>');
```

But when I click on remove, it doesn't work:

```
$('#us').click(function(){

    $('li').remove('#Pallet+i+');

});
```

Any advice?

Comment: You should provide more code context in question, it's quite unclear what you are asking here

Comment: Please tell, what you want to remove by clicking on what????
Its unclear question

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove by class instead of ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$('#us').click(function(){

$('li').remove('#Pallet'+ i);

});
```

Because you put all into a string `remove('#Pallet+i+');` and it is not a valid selector.

Comment: I could be wrong but unless you're applying this event every time `i` increments, you'll lose the scope of `i`.

Comment: @Freak_Droid Ya, just saw it now. I was guessing OP was setting code in a loop but with so less relevant code in question, we can just guessing

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$('#us').click(function(){

    $('li').remove('#Pallet' + i);

});
```

Because using `$('li').remove('#Pallet+i+');` makes it think to also remove an element with the name `i` and it  is not found and then it is an invalid selector because of the `+` on the end. It also makes it think the `+i+` part is part of the string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is easier:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#us', function(){
    $('li #Pallet'+i).remove();
});
```